# OpenGL program doesn't start in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, opengl, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator on linux mint and I try to run an opengl program.
The building doesn't give any errors, yet when I try to run the program inside Qt Creator, a terminal window appears, and nothing else happens. When I run the program directly in terminal I get the following output:

```
OpenGL version supported by this platform (3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.40): 
OpenGL 3.3.0 NVIDIA 295.40, GLSL 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
Ready for OpenGL 2.0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Aquarium");
    glutDisplayFunc(onDisplay);
    glutMouseFunc(onMouse);
    glutIdleFunc(onIdle);
    glutKeyboardFunc(onKeyboard);
    glutReshapeFunc(onReshape);

    printf("OpenGL version supported by this platform (%s): \n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    printf("OpenGL %s, GLSL %s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION),glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION));

    glewInit();

    if (glewIsSupported("GL_VERSION_2_0"))
        printf("Ready for OpenGL 2.0\n");
    else {
        printf("OpenGL 2.0 not supported\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    onInitialization();

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

I have defined the event handlers, and I have the onInitialization() method too.
If I try to printf something in the beginning of the onInitialization() method, the program doesn't write anything else apart from the rows I wrote earlier. So it doesn't step inside 
onInitialization() I think. I can't even debug this program in Qt Creator. What can cause this? And what can cause that I can't start the program inside Qt Creator? I have a .pro file:

```
QT       -= gui core

TARGET = main
CONFIG   += console

TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += /usr/lib/libglut.so /usr/lib/compiz/libopengl.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

With the same setting I've been able to run the program under Windows (of course the LIBS were different there).

The onInitialization():

```
void onInitialization( ) {

    printf("onInitialization");

   soft.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5., 5., 5.));
   soft.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));
   soft.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5, -5., 5.));
   soft.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));
   soft.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5., -5., -5.));
   soft.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));

   soft2.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5., 5., 5.));
   soft2.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));
   soft2.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5, -5., 5.));
   soft2.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));
   soft2.controlpoints.push_back(Point(5., -5., -5.));
   soft2.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));
   soft2.controlpoints.push_back(Point(-5., 5., -5.));
   soft2.speeds.push_back(Point(0., 0., 0.));

   soft.set_r();
   soft2.set_r();

   aquarium.objects.push_back(&water);
   aquarium.objects.push_back(&fish);
   aquarium.objects.push_back(&field);
   aquarium.objects.push_back(&soft2);

   aquarium.createMaterials();

   aquarium.createVoxelArray();

   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   lastMovingTime = 0.;

   setShadowMapShaders();
   setAquariumShaders();
```

}

It doesn't print even the "onInitialization" string. The objects in the method are global variables, and all of the methods that are called here is implemented. What can cause that it doesn't print the "onInitialization" string? soft.controlpoints, soft.speeds, and aquarium.object are public fields. Even if I comment everything else, the string doesn't appear, but the window is created. And it's still not running from inside the Qt Creator.

Comment: Why aren't you checking [`glewInit()`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html)'s return code?

Comment: Apparently the problem lies somewhere in the `onInitialization` function. Please post the code of that one, so that we can help you.

Comment: After a bit of debugging the problem seems to be the glShaderSource() method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with file reader method (that reads in the GLSL shaders codes) and this was because Qt Creator's working directory wasn't set on the directory which contained the shaders source files.